# Was Birdemic intended to be a bad movie?

Tags: analysis, production, reception, birdemic

I would like to know if Birdemic was intended as a funny non-serious movie or if it was really made with the intention of producing a genuinely scary movie that just got bad. Were they serious when they filmed it? Did they aim the bottom of the IMDb list on purpose? Should I see the movie as a joke?

**Is there any evidence from the production circumstances to make a reasonable conclusion if Birdemic was deliberately planned as a bad trashy movie?**

Comment: Is it an *Asylum* movie? I recently read an insider article from a screenwriter that more or less said that *Asylum* genuinely didn't know how crappy their movies are (if that's the truth or not).

Comment: No it's not an Asylum movie

Comment: Not duplicated from [here, but discussed](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/was-sharknado-planned-as-a-trash-movie)

Comment: In the interviews with cast / crew I've seen, the director (James Nguyen) seems legitimately clueless. He made a scary and insightful movie as far as he knew. Part 2 was just as bad and had all the same cast and story-beats. And his first movie, Julie and Jack, was just as bad.

Comment: Part 2 was filmed as a response to the success of the first film, ironically as a result of its cult (rifftrax) status. It's unlikely that Nguyen is unaware of how bad the first one was

Comment: He knows now, but didn't **during production,** ala the OP's Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very short answer is no. Nguyen seems to be genuinely <s>insane</s> unaware that his movie is laughable. He honestly believes that audiences are laughing *with* the movie and that it's an intelligent 'think piece' and a romance film (!) to boot.

If you want to stare into the eyes of madness, you can watch the interviews below

> **Interviewer:** *"Do you think it's a good film?"*
>
> **Nguyen:** *"I think that it's a good film, based on the condition of what I had
>   to work with"*

and

> I see a similar pattern, is that the audience really likes the film. I
>   think the majority of the audience [are] really laughing with the
>   movie, and they were really experiencing the scenes of the film,
>   scene-to-scene. It’s like they were sitting at the midnight showing of
>   the ‘Rocky Horror [Picture Show]’. You know?
>    - <sub><sup>http://bloody-disgusting.com/interviews/23593/special-interview-birdemic-shock-and-terror-director-james-nguyen/</sup></sub>

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).